# Expanding rows for hist in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data frame consisting of the columns; "name", "time", "count". Showing how many items took a given length of time. I would like to be able to draw a histogram based on the counts (and have hist() pick the boundaries etc.)

```
+------+------+-------+
| name | time | count |
+------+------+-------+
| foo  |    5 |     5 |
| foo  |   10 |     8 |
| foo  |   15 |     6 |
| foo  |   20 |     8 |
| bar  |    5 |     7 |
| bar  |   10 |     4 |
| bar  |   15 |     9 |
| bar  |   20 |    10 |
+------+------+-------+
```

From this I would like to be able to create histograms of times by name and times across the board. However, hist() counts up rows itself, I already have the counts in a count column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to use a barplot instead of a histogram.

```
library(lattice)
barchart( count ~ time | name, data=d )

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=time, y=count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid( ~ name )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could regenerate the data and make the histogram by repeating each value count times...

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = c("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", 
"bar", "bar"), V2 = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L), 
    V3 = c(5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 10L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


hist(as.numeric(unlist(apply(d,1,function(x){rep(x[2],time=x[3])}))))
```